# html page shakes a lot during DOM operations, how to deal with it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm using DOM to operate on the pages depending on the backend JSON data, say, some tables on the page may have 10-50 rows of the data, during the time, i saw the page shakes a lot, looks not nice to the users, 
is there any good way to deal with this?

something codes to demo the effect is like this... i've a table in the middle, with an unknown size...

test

```
window.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(createTable, 3000);
}


function createTable(){
    var table = document.createElement("table");
        for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = "row " + i;

        tr.appendChild(td);

        table.appendChild(tr);
        }

        document.getElementById("tablewrapper").appendChild(table);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:300px; background-color:blue;">
       hello
    </div>

    <div id="tablewrapper">
    </div>

    <div style="width:300px;background-color:red">
    world
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: is it really a pure javascript? or it uses jquery with easing?. is it shaking in all browsers(firefox, chrome, etc)?

Comment: Can you show relevant parts of your code and a demo page?

Comment: i added the codes to demo the effect

Comment: Could you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I don't see any shaking - http://jsfiddle.net/u8pfc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you should put a loading mask on top of it so the user can't see the shaking.

In most frameworks there are utility functions like described [here](http://aboukone.com/2011/08/08/extjs-show-a-loading-mask-during-ajax-calls/) for ExtJS or as [plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/) for jQuery but you can easily do it on your own (just a div on top of your area or the whole page, hide the div when your code is done).